# How do I use a temporary secret Access key and access key ID in Amazon S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I have a temporary access key and secret access key that I have to use in Amazon S3. I never used AWS before so I'm very confused. How do I use my credentials? Do I need to make my own AWS account and use the credentials in there? I'm given a bucket name and bucket location for Amazon S3. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to Amazon Web Services and looks like you want to use Python, here is a good place to start with that will get you up and running.

See:

[Quickstart](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html)

This guide details the steps needed to install or update the AWS SDK for Python.

The SDK is composed of two key Python packages: Botocore (the library providing the low-level functionality shared between the Python SDK and the AWS CLI) and Boto3 (the package implementing the Python SDK itself).